# If every finite subset of a theory has an infinite model then the theory has an infinite model

Tags: logic, model-theory, filters

Consider the famous compactness theorem, one of the first theorems in model theory: Let $T$ be a theory, i.e., a set of first-order sentences. If every finite subset of $T$ has a model, then the whole set $T$ itself has a model.

It is well-known that this theorem fails if one just considers finite models. I asked myself the question? Is it true if one just considers infinite models? That is, if every finite subset of $T$ has an infinite model, does $T$ have an infinite model?

I think one can deduce this by applying the compactness theorem to an extended theory $T$ in an extended signature. Let $\tau$ be the signature of $T$. We can get a new signature $\tau' := \tau\sqcup\{s, 0\}$ by adding a unary function symbol $s$ and a constant symbol $0$ to $\tau$. Now consider the theory $T'$ over $\tau'$ defined by:
$$T' := T\cup\{\quad\forall x(s(x)\not=0)\,\land\, \forall x, y (s(x) = s(y)\Rightarrow x = y)\quad\}.$$
Let $F'$ be an arbitrary finite subset of $T'$. $F'$ induces a finite subset $F$ of $T$ by deleting $\forall x(s(x)\not=0)\,\land\, \forall x, y (s(x) = s(y)\Rightarrow x = y)$ if it happens to be in $F'$ (otherwise $F=F'$). By assumption, $F$ has an infinite model $\mathcal A$. Since $\mathcal A$ is infinite, this model can be transformed into a model of $F'$ by choosing $0\in A$ and $s\colon A\to A$ such that $\mathcal A\models \forall x(s(x)\not=0)\,\land\, \forall x, y (s(x) = s(y)\Rightarrow x = y)$. By compactness, $T'$ has a model, which must be infinite. Thus also $T$ has an infinite model.

First question: is my proof correct? Is there a simpler proof?

Second question: in my proof, I use the compacntess theorem as a blackbox. But maybe it's possible to directly construct an infinite model of $T$. Using the standard ultraproduct argument, this would be trivially possible if the ultraproduct of infinite structures is infinite (no matter which ultrafilter we choose). Is this true?

Comment: Regarding you last question not only you can say that the product is infinite, it's not hard to bound the cardinality of the ultraproduct $\prod_i \kappa_i/\mathcal{F}$, where the $\kappa_i$ are cardinals, as $\min_i\{\kappa_i\}\leq |\prod_i \kappa_i/\mathcal{F}|\leq \prod_i\kappa_i$. (There is a lot of literature about cardinalities of ultraproducts and much more can be said of course, but that's enough for your question!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, your proof is correct.
2. Yes, ultraproduct of infinite models is infinite: consider the formulas
   $$\exists x_1\dots\exists x_n:\bigwedge_{i\ne j} \lnot(x_i=x_j) $$

Comment: Thanks, concerning the first question: I also asked whether there is a simpler proof. Could you say something about this?

Comment: Well, the ultraproduct approach seems simpler. But, purely syntactically, the additional formula you present (or the infinite family from my answer) is indeed required.

Comment: To use your infinite family of formulas is better, because with my formula one also has to prove that on each infinite set $0$ and $s$ can be imposed such that the formula holds.